# Dictionary Optional? Confusion in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, option-type, xcode6

I know there are a lot of posts on this, but I can't seem to figure out what's going on.  The dictionary prints fine.  It has a list of words with the number of letters for that word as the value.  I want to check if another string is in the list.   I read a bunch on optionals, but apparently I'm missing something.  I think it has to do with that of course.

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wordlist", ofType: "txt")
    var content = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)?.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")



    var myDict = [String : Int]()



    let compareWord : String? = "TEST"

            if let content = content {
                for word in 100 ..< 105
                {
                    myDict[content[word]] = countElements(content[word])
                }
            }

    println("\(myDict)")



    var num : Int? = 0
    println("Num: \(myDict[compareWord!])")
    if let num : Int = myDict[compareWord!] {
        println("\(compareWord) is a word with \(num) letters")
    }
    else
    {
        println("Wasn't a word")
    }
```

**** Updated with a bit more detail of the code.

---

Here is what I get when I print a section of the dictionary.

[ABBOTSHIPS
: 11, ABBREVIATED
: 12, ABBOTS
: 7, ABBOTSHIP
: 10, ABBREVIATE
: 11]

If I set the test word to one of them I always get nil when checking for it.  It seems to work fine when I manually type things in under the playground.

Comment: Can you provide your code with sample data so that we can run it and see what fails?

Comment: You code works fine. What is your question?

Comment: Sure... It always returns as not being in the dictionary.  I'll put some sample data in a sec.

Comment: If I just try to print myDict[compareWord!] then I get nil also.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint or `Log(...)` to see the contents of `myDict` variable just before the `if` clause. I expect it to miss the value.

Comment: Can you post the whole code for the function were you do `if let num = myDict[compareWord!] {`?

Comment: I put the part where the data gets loaded, maybe its in there...

Comment: are you sure that by using `componentsSeparatedByString("\n")` there are no `\r` around?

Comment: You might wanna use `newlineCharacterSet` method of `NSCharacterSet` instead of `\n`

Comment: Awesome... I replaced \n with \n\r   and it works fine.  I will look at your tip also.  Thanks.  If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: glad it worked - btw I suggested the same in the other question you posted, maybe not so explicitly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `componentsSeparatedByString("\n")` doesn't leave any other character, such as `\r`, at the beginning or end of each extracted strings.